# Ionic 3 cannot convert filter() result into array

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, filter, ionic3

I have the initial array of data `dataToDisplay` and the array that I need to add filtered arrays into it `dataToDisplay`. I used `.filter()` to do so:

```
this.dataToDisplay = this.dataToDisplay.filter((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
  if(res.type==this.filterArray['typeOfIns'])
  {
    this.dataToFilter = res;
    console.log(this.dataToFilter)

    //this.dataToFilter = res;
    //console.log(this.dataToFilter)
  }

})
```

I got an error saying:

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed

The result at line 58: `console.log(this.dataToFilter)` is returning the right arrays but cannot be displayed and binded into the page.

`dataToDisplay` is having the following structure:

```
dataToDisplay = [
    {id:.., type:.., name:..},
    {id:.., type:.., name:..}
]
```

Comment: can you share dataToDisplay? and generally add more context as its unclear what is array and what is array of arrays?

Comment: check the edit please @SergeyRudenko

Comment: The callback of the filter method should return a boolean. It seems you do not return a boolean there. Maybe check out how [filter works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: cool, last bit - can you share what is filterArray object?

Comment: It worked as @Phonolog links said, just a simple return is enough, I will post an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code :

```js
this.dataToDisplay = this.dataToDisplay.filter((res)=>{
  return res.type==this.filterArray['typeOfIns']
})
```

This will done all the work.